# Unable to view the Apache test page

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, lamp

I'm trying to start install LAMP in my EC2 instance. I have followed all the steps in this website
( https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-lamp-amazon-linux-2.html )but unable to see the test page coming up once I open my DNS id.  Checked whether the service is running by typing in sudo systemctl is-enabled httpd and it comes up as enabled. My port 80 is also open. Please help!

Comment: what about `curl localhost` on the instance?

Comment: Use curl localhost on the instance I'm SSH'd in?

Comment: yes. Does it work?